# Live shrinking of root partition has failed on Linux Mint

Tags: filesystems, fdisk, fsck

**Steps taken:**

*Used fdisk to delete the existing root partition and created a new root partition (PV) starting on the same block

*Added the 'a' flag using fdisk to make it bootable as /boot is under the root partition

After rebooting, I became stuck at the GRUB screen with the error "attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'"

After using a live USB here is my current partition table:

```
   mint@mint ~ $ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0008fb69

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    41945087    20971520   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       609040382   625141759     8050689    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       609040384   625141759     8050688   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I'm not sure why I'm receiving this error because I don't think the partitions have to be contiguous.

```
mint@mint ~ $ sudo fsck /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Error reading block 37781504 (Invalid argument).  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? no
Superblock has an invalid journal (inode 8).
Clear<y>? no
fsck.ext4: Illegal inode number while checking ext3 journal for /dev/sda1

/dev/sda1: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********
```

I was going to re-size my filesystem using resize2fs after resizing the partition but this error from fsck seems like I should deal with that first..
After looking at solutions it seems that if I clear the superblock the filesystem will lose its journal and become ext2.
I'm not sure what's going on and would like some advice.

Thanks.

******EDIT**********

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   154   130   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       1266
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       8446
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   093   093   000    Old_age   Always       -       5213
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2182
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       31259
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       68
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   157   157   000    Old_age   Always       -       130128
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   105   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       38
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]


SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
```

Comment: Are you sure the volume wasn't mounted? Some live USB media automatically mounts disks. Does `smartctl -a /dev/sda` report any errors?

Comment: @Gilles added the output, it doesn't look like there's any errors. But re-confirming, partitions don't have to occupy contiguous blocks of memory, correct?
From memory when I used a live USB it was listed as /dev/sdb1, so it shouldn't have affected this partitioning. It didn't occupy any partitions on /dev/sda.